# Parsing RSS2 In PHP

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to get content from an RSS2 feed from one of my sites and use it in another site.

The feed is [here](http://tripleax.com/john/?feed=rss2).  And the code I'm using is taken from [this](http://www.softarea51.com/tutorials/parse_rss_with_php.html) nice site and has been modified like the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://tripleax.com/john/?feed=rss2');
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    print('<div style="width:100%" class="option"><strong>');
    $a = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    print("$a");
    print('</strong><br /><span class="option">');
    $a = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    print("$a");`
}
```

The problem I'm having is, I want to display the entire post's contents.  And the description is a sort of the teaser.  Changing `$node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue` to `$node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->nodeValue` gives me nothing, and `content:encoded` is no better.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to solving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need getElementsByTagNameNS()

Comment: Thanks! That's an even better suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Silly you!  Use `$node->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue`!